# How to get a downloadable url of S3 bucket itself not an object url using python, boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I have lots of files and sub-folders inside of which there are some folders and files all of this is inside an S3 bucket. So I know how to download the files as there is a object url clicking on that, we will be able to download the file.

**Requirement**

But my requirement is such that I need a downloadable url of the S3 bucket such that clicking on it, I will be able to download all the contents intact like files, sub-folders etc in the bucket as it is.

```
import os, boto3, params, subprocess

path  = "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\BackUp"

subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'sync', path, 's3://axis-tax-drive'])
```

I wrote this code to *upload* the content to S3, now I'd like to get a downloadable url of the S3 bucket as I mentioned above.

Could the requirement be satisified by creating an access point or anything like that ..

I'd like to know all the possibilities.

Please Help..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such concept as a "downloadable url of the S3 bucket". Amazon S3 is an **object storage service**. You can download individual objects, but not the whole bucket. You might want to use the AWS CLI (as per your example), which can upload/download objects, but it simply copies objects individually.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Is it possible by any of the approaches mentioned by Max-Raba-Streicher ?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you are actually wanting to achieve?

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Nothing much complex John, just a URL of the S3 bucket by clicking on which I'll be able to download all the contents of the bucket intact.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Just like how the object url lets me download the object, I need S3 url to download the S3 bucket so to speak.

Comment: What do you mean by "download the bucket"? A bucket can contain multiple objects. What do you expect to happen when you put this URL into a web browser? What would it download -- multiple files, or a single Zip files, or something else?

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Download the bucket meaning that I should be able to download all the files, sub-folders etc.. that are in the bucket as it is on clicking that url. When I put this URL in the browser, it must prompt me to download the bucket, could be in the form of zip folder(consisting of all the contents inside that bucket ) or in the form of normal folder with the folder name being the bucket name itself.

Answer (score 0):

- You can make the bucket public and download links are then straight forward.
- You can have something which generates presigned url which are valid for a certain period of time: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html or with the cli: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html

Comment: @Max-Raba_Streicher I don't want a Url for the object, instead I want the downloadable url for the bucket itself, so that I can just download the bucket or contents in it regardless of there being sub-folders or files in that bucket by just clicking on the url .

Comment: @CharliePuth The whole bucket as zip? Then you need to program something e.g. in a lambda via API gateway. When it is public, you need to config it as website, then everybody can download https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html

Comment: @ Max-Raba-Streicher I'd be glad if you could elaborate a bit about the lambda API Gateway approach

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "download a bucket from a URL". The API calls for Amazon S3 can only download a single object. Nor is it possible to ask S3 to provide a Zip of multiple files stored in S3.

However, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to do it...

Your code shows an example of using the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 sync <path> s3://bucketname
```

The AWS CLI is a Python program that calls the S3 API. For the above command, it lists the contents of `path` and then uses a loop to call the `PutObject()` command to upload one file at a time. However, it's a little bit smart because it uses multi-threading to upload multiple files at the same time (but each upload is done by a separate API call).

You could use **the same command in reverse to download a bucket** to your computer:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname <path>
```

Or, you could write your own program that loops through the files and downloads them individually.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the API Gateway / Lambda approach.

Suppose you have an Lambda which downloads all objects from your S3 bucket and puts it into a zip like this:

```
import logging
import os
from io import BytesIO
from typing import Dict, Any
from zipfile import ZipFile

import boto3

LOGGER = logging.getLogger("zip-bucket")
logging.basicConfig(level="INFO",)
'''
  this is the method which is invoked by the lambda. if you upload it AWS lambda, this is your method which will be called.
  not quite sure about what is in the event, but I do not need it for now.
'''
def handle(event: Dict[str, Any], context: Dict[str, Any]):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    bucket = os.environ["BUCKET"]
    s3_objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket)
    zip_buffer = BytesIO()
    with ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w') as myzip:
        for s3_object in s3_objects['Contents']:
            key = s3_object['Key']
            LOGGER.info("Zipping %s", key)
            myzip.writestr(key, s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read())
    myzip.close()
    return {
            'headers': { "Content-Type": " application/zip; charset=binary" },
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': zip_buffer.getvalue(),
            'isBase64Encoded': False
        }



if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipfile = open("result.zip", "wb")
    zipfile.write(handle(None, None)['body'])
    zipfile.close()
```

You can run it locally for testing or you create an AWS lambda. Since the only dependency is the aws-sdk (boto3) which is provided it runs out of the box. Keep in mind, you have to give the lambda execution role permissions to your s3 bucket (ListBucket and GetObject).
Now your request handling logic is in place. What is missing now is some kind of HTTP endpoint. Here API Gateway comes into play.

In AWS go to API Gateway and create I suppose a HTTP Gateway, because this is the most simple one. You can connect previously created lambda when creating a new api. If you do it via the AWS Console, it will create policies in your lambda on the fly.
After the you get an http endpoint where you can download the zip. If it does not work you need to look into the Cloudwatch logs either or the lambda or your api gateway.

This link might be interesting for you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html

Keep in mind that is approach has no authentication build in!!